# ReactJS Not Found The requested URL /AboutMe was not found on this server

Tags: reactjs, web, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I created a react app (also use react-router) without server and I build it. 
After I upload it to the hosting it works fine until I tried to write the url to the address bar,
it display  "**Not Found The requested URL /AboutMe was not found on this server."**

Do I need also to create a server to catch the url (/AboutMe) everytime I try to write it to the address bar?

```
<Router history={history}>  
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path = "/" render = {() => (<Home value = {info} />)} />
                        <Route exact path = "/AboutMe" render = {() => (<AboutMe value = {info} />)}/>
                        <Route component = {NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Can you show us your routes code?

Comment: sure , I will edit my question

Comment: Quick solution use hash router

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your webserver in SPA mode (redirect all requests to /index.html). Example of nginx configuration

```
root /var/www/your_site;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:
Use hash router like this:
`import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';`